# Jquery - Cannot set keydown event when put cursor in iframe (text editor)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to call a "keydown" event for textbox and texteditor, using some function with jquery (ex: press Alt+1 to lowercase, alt+2 to uppercase)
I'm using this js to set keydown event:

```
$(window).keydown(function (e) { alert("some thing"); });
```

That is OK with the textbox (

I'm trying to set the "keydown" event for my texteditor with js:

```
        window.onload = function () {
        $('iframe').find('body').context.onkeydown = function () {
            alert("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        };
    }
```

That js runs when my cursor is out of my text editor, when it is in my cursor in, then nothing runs.

This is Developer Console F12
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKyHF.jpg

I searched in google and stackoverflow a lot for a solution, but found nothing. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

First of all look at [same-origin policy article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

You are trying to access iframe content from the outer document. If your case satisfies same-origin policy rules (your iframe content if served from the same domain) then you will be able to operate on the iframe content DOM.

Anyway using jQuery from the outer document is not a good idea.

Comment: Yes, my project is MVC and in my cshtml file I call a function from an jquery file  `<link href="/Content/assets/scripts/PostingTool/TextEditTool.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Content/assets/scripts/PostingTool/jquery-fieldselection.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Content/assets/scripts/PostingTool/jquery.texteditortool.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("body").textEditorTool({//something});
`
Any process I code in jquery.texteditortool.js file. So any solution?